# Regex only working on one line of a docx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, docx

I am trying to read a docx file and extract data between certain words into a list. I would like to find all the instances where the data matches, which I do using regex. I only get an output if the data is on the same line, I reckon it's something to do with the type str printing after each space (no clue why this happens) example below:

Code below

```
import re
from docx import Document

document = Document('myfile.docx')
lst=[]
for para in document.paragraphs:
    orig = para.text
    orig= str(orig)
    print(type(orig))
    output= re.findall(r'sent1([^(]*)sent2',orig)
    print(re.findall(r'sent1([^(]*)sent2',orig))
    lst.append(output)
```

Output of my file on screen:

```
Heading


Some data here. sent1 this is my data xyz, hello sent2.


Heading 2

Another paragraph here with spaced below.
```

Output of my file when showing the type. It's a string I have no idea why it's printing like this:

```
<class 'str'>
My data here
<class 'str'>
sent 1 and more data this space
<class 'str'>
sent2 here
sent1 example2 sent2
```

Desired output (list of all the characters captured between sent1 and sent2 through the document)

```
output=['and more data this space', 'example2']
```

Current output

```
output=['example2']
```

Comment: It is strange, how can `print(re.findall(r'sent1([^(]*)sent2',orig))` print a string? It must be a list.

Comment: Just looking at your regex it shouldn't match, I think you want ```r'sent.*1([^(]*)sent.*2'```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes output is a list (will update my q to make it clear!)

Comment: @itwasthekix hey so I tried it for my personal example which is just two words, like 'Header' and 'Final' so adding the `.*1` doesn't make any difference

Comment: @qwerty12 Ah sorry I was just looking at your example where you have 'sent 1 and more data this space sent2'.  To match that statement you need to take into account the space between "sent" and "1", one way to do that is with ".*" (any character 0 or more times).  In your actual 'Header' and 'Final' don't need ".*".

Comment: @itwasthekix no worries and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd just merge everything into one giant string and regex match on that.  E.g. so something like this:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('myfile.docx')
 
fulltext = []
for para in document.paragraphs:
    fullText.append(paragraph.text)
fulltext = ' '.join(fulltext)

output = re.findall(r'word1 .* word2', fulltext)
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way that I can put each instance found as an element within the list? Currently it is all being appended as one huge list.

Comment: You can do it in a for loop, just delete the join line and then: for i in fulltext: output.append(re.findall(r'word1 .* word2', fulltext)).  Where output starts as an empty list and then becomes a list of lists of which contain the matches for the corresponding line.